# wave file read using psf_sndReadFloatFrames (portsf library)

Tags: c, audio

I study sound reading, and I found that i don't understand part

```
framesread = psf_sndReadFloatFrames(ifd,frame,1);
        for(i=0; i < props.chans; i++ )         
            frame[i] *= ampfac;
```

buf is one byte float number. what is mean this value?

angle? radian?   is this always use only one byte(one channel)

Comment: `buf` is very likely a pointer to an array of floats (in other words, to the first float in that array). It is not a "one byte float number", whatever that may be.

Answer (score 0):

In that declaration, `buf` is a pointer to (the first element of) an array of floats. There are no "one byte float numbers" that I am aware of.

It is ***probably*** used like:

```
#define NUM_CHANNELS (2)
#define BUF_LEN (4096)

float buffer[BUF_LEN * NUM_CHANNELS];

...

int frames_read = BUF_LEN; 
while (frames_read == BUF_LEN)
{
    frames_read = psf_sndReadFloatFrames(myfiledesc, buffer, BUF_LEN);
    /* process data in buffer */
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, are you audio engineer?  my book write for gain change..   just read one byte use float variable and  add float value to reading value.   I want to know about wave file byte value.